# label justified right on big screens but centered on small screens

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to center my labels on small screens but justify them right on big screens.

`css`

```css
.left-form{
    text-align: right;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    label{
        text-align: center !important;
    }
}
```

`html`

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col -xs -6 left-form">
        <label for="codeDemarche">label</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" disabled id="codeDemarche" name="codeDemarche">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *mobile first* approach. Start with how it will look like in mobile devices and then add media queries for bigger screens.

Also, use the same selectors!

```
.left-form {
    text-align: center; /* default */
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { /* only "big" screens */
    .left-form { /* instead of label */
        text-align: right;
    }
}
```